# How to augment JQueryStatic with SignalR methods

Tags: jquery, typescript, signalr, definitelytyped

I am using TypeScript 2.0 and the definitely typed declaration file for jQuery. I am also using SignalR. SignalR depends on jQuery and adds some properties to it. As an example you can write "$.connection.hub.logging = true;" where SignalR has added "connection" to jQuery.

The definitely typed declaration file for jQuery defines the interface JQueryStatic but does not export JQueryStatic because only $ is being exported. $ is of type JQueryStatic.

My question is, how do I write code using TypeScript 2.0 which augments the interface JQueryStatic  with a definition for a new property p1, which "connection" is an example of?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple ways:

1. Make sure you are using the latest version of the [SignalR type
   definition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/signalr). It looks as if the [SignalR definition is already augmenting jQueryStatic](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/signalr/signalr.d.ts#L361-L365).

---

2. Use [TypeScript's declaration merging](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to augment jQueryStatic by adding the snippet below to the top of your TypeScript file.

   `declare global {
       interface JQueryStatic {
         signalR: SignalR;
         connection: SignalR;
         hubConnection: SignalR.Hub.HubCreator;
       }
   }`